# How I change color of my input/label when i clicked?

Tags: html, css

I'm in a personal project learning about programming, and i want to be able to change the color of my labels when i click on them, it only works when i hover the mouse over them but it doesn't stay that change i leave my code below

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>MOKEPON!</title>
        <script src="./js/mokepon.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Mokepon! </h1>
        <section id="choosePet">
            

            <h2 class="subtitle">Elige tu mascota:</h2>

            <div class="btnStats">
                <label class="petCard" for="garydous">
                    <p>Garydous</p>
                    <img src="resources/Garydous.png" alt="Garydous">
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="garydous" />
                
                <label class="petCard" for="chikbo">
                    <p>Chikbo</p>
                    <img  src="resources/picathor.png" alt="Chikbo">
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="chikbo" />
                
                <label class="petCard" for="smyglet">
                    <p>smyglet</p>
                    <img src="resources/smyglet.png" alt="Smyglet">
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="smyglet" />
            </div>
            

            <button id="btnPet">Vamos a Luchar</button>
        </section>

        <section id="chooseAttack">
            <h2>Elige tu ataque:</h2>

            <p>Tu mascota <span id="allyPet"></span> tiene <span id="hpAllyPet">3</span> vidas</p>
            <p>La mascota <span id="enemyPet"></span> del enemigo tiene <span id="hpEnemyPet">3</span> vidas</p>

            <p id="attacks">
                <button id="btnFire">Fuego </button>
                <button id="btnWater">Agua </button>
                <button id="btnPlant">Tierra </button>
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="alertsCombat">
        </section>

        <section id="reboot">
            <button id="btnReboot">Reiniciar</button>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

body{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    background-color: #10A19D;
}


input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
input[type='radio'].petCard:checked + label {
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    border: #f0f8ff;
}
#title{
    color:#FF7000;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center; 
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    
}

#choosePet{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.subtitle{
    color: #FFBF00;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.petCard{
    width: 250px;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #77037B;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    color: #10A19D;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.petCard img{
    justify-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    

}

.btnStats{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 15px;
}
label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
.subtitle {
    font-size: 50px;
}

#btnPet{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    background-color: #B799FF;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow:
    inset -3px 3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    inset -3px -3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    inset 3px 1px 2px 2px #ACBCFF;
    position: relative;
}
#btnPet:focus{
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
#bntPet:visited{
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
#btnPet:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #B799FF;
    box-shadow:
    -3px 3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    -3px -3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    3px 1px 2px 2px #ACBCFF;
}
input:focus .label {
  color: #B799FF;
}
input:blur .label{
    color: #f0f8ff;
}
```

JS

```
let ataqueJugador
let ataqueEnemigo
let vidasJugador = 3
let vidasEnemigo = 3

function iniciarJuego() {
    let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('chooseAttack')
    sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'none'

    let sectionreboot = document.getElementById('reboot')
    sectionreboot.style.display = 'none'
    
    let botonMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('btnPet')
    botonMascotaJugador.addEventListener('click', seleccionarMascotaJugador)

    let botonFuego = document.getElementById('btnFire')
    botonFuego.addEventListener('click', ataqueFuego)
    let botonAgua = document.getElementById('btnWater')
    botonAgua.addEventListener('click', ataqueAgua)
    let botonTierra = document.getElementById('btnPlant')
    botonTierra.addEventListener('click', ataqueTierra)

    let botonReboot = document.getElementById('btnReboot')
    botonReboot.addEventListener('click', rebootGame)
}

function seleccionarMascotaJugador() {
    let sectionSeleccionarMascota = document.getElementById('choosePet')
    sectionSeleccionarMascota.style.display = 'none'
    
    let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('chooseAttack')
    sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'block'
    
    let inputGarydous = document.getElementById('garydous')
    let inputChikbo = document.getElementById('chikbo')
    let inputSmyglet = document.getElementById('smyglet')
    let spanMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('allyPet')
    
    if (inputGarydous.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Garydous';
    } else if (inputChikbo.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Chikbo';
    } else if (inputSmyglet.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Smyglet';
    } else {
        alert('Selecciona una mascota')
    }

    seleccionarMascotaEnemigo()
}

function seleccionarMascotaEnemigo() {
    let mascotaAleatoria = aleatorio(1,3)
    let spanMascotaEnemigo = document.getElementById('enemyPet')

    if (mascotaAleatoria == 1) {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Garydous'
    } else if (mascotaAleatoria == 2) {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Chikbo'
    } else {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Smyglet'
    }
}

function ataqueFuego() {
    ataqueJugador = 'FUEGO'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueAgua() {
    ataqueJugador = 'AGUA'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueTierra() {
    ataqueJugador = 'TIERRA'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}

function ataqueAleatorioEnemigo() {
    let ataqueAleatorio = aleatorio(1,3)
    
    if (ataqueAleatorio == 1) {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'FUEGO'
    } else if (ataqueAleatorio == 2) {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'AGUA'
    } else {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'TIERRA'
    }

    combate()
}

function combate() {
    let spanVidasJugador = document.getElementById('hpAllyPet')
    let spanVidasEnemigo = document.getElementById('hpEnemyPet')
    
    if(ataqueEnemigo == ataqueJugador) {
        crearMensaje("EMPATE")
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'FUEGO' && ataqueEnemigo == 'TIERRA') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'AGUA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'FUEGO') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'TIERRA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'AGUA') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else {
        crearMensaje("PERDISTE")
        vidasJugador--
        spanVidasJugador.innerHTML = vidasJugador
    }

    revisarVidas()
}

function revisarVidas() {
    if (vidasEnemigo == 0) {
        crearMensajeFinal("FELICITACIONES! Ganaste :)")
    } else if (vidasJugador == 0) {
        crearMensajeFinal('Lo siento, perdiste :(')
    }
}

function crearMensaje(resultado) {
    let sectionalertsCombat = document.getElementById('alertsCombat')
    
    let parrafo = document.createElement('p')
    parrafo.innerHTML = 'Tu mascota atacó con ' + ataqueJugador + ', las mascota del enemigo atacó con ' + ataqueEnemigo + '- ' + resultado

    sectionalertsCombat.appendChild(parrafo)
}

function crearMensajeFinal(resultadoFinal) {
    let sectionalertsCombat = document.getElementById('alertsCombat')
    
    let parrafo = document.createElement('p')
    parrafo.innerHTML = resultadoFinal

    sectionalertsCombat.appendChild(parrafo)

    let botonFuego = document.getElementById('btnFire')
    botonFuego.disabled = true
    let botonAgua = document.getElementById('btnWater')
    botonAgua.disabled = true
    let botonTierra = document.getElementById('btnPlant')
    botonTierra.disabled = true

    let sectionreboot = document.getElementById('reboot')
    sectionreboot.style.display = 'block'
}

function rebootGame() {
    location.reload()
}

function aleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

window.addEventListener('load', iniciarJuego)
```

i tried several ideas but still not working that idea, if somebody can help me

Comment: You mean when you click the label, it will just change it's color?

Comment: yes, I tried change the radio for checkbox and made a neew function in js but when I clicked, the color is marked in the next label :(

Comment: In your current code, can you point it out where this *change the radio for checkbox and made a neew function in js but when I clicked, the color is marked in the next label*? In addition, can you add draft or image of the result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I missed that you wanted to go with radiobuttons:

In your HTML it seems like you should put the `input` before its `label` instead of the other way around.

Additionally in your CSS the `input[type='radio'].petCard:checked + label` cannot target anything. Your class `.petCard` is the label of the input, which seems to not be the child of the input. That's why changibg it to `input[type='radio']:checked + label` seems to achieve it. Now the selected card changes the color after clicking on it.

```js
let ataqueJugador
let ataqueEnemigo
let vidasJugador = 3
let vidasEnemigo = 3

function iniciarJuego() {
    let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('chooseAttack')
    sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'none'

    let sectionreboot = document.getElementById('reboot')
    sectionreboot.style.display = 'none'
    
    let botonMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('btnPet')
    botonMascotaJugador.addEventListener('click', seleccionarMascotaJugador)

    let botonFuego = document.getElementById('btnFire')
    botonFuego.addEventListener('click', ataqueFuego)
    let botonAgua = document.getElementById('btnWater')
    botonAgua.addEventListener('click', ataqueAgua)
    let botonTierra = document.getElementById('btnPlant')
    botonTierra.addEventListener('click', ataqueTierra)

    let botonReboot = document.getElementById('btnReboot')
    botonReboot.addEventListener('click', rebootGame)
}

function seleccionarMascotaJugador() {
    let sectionSeleccionarMascota = document.getElementById('choosePet')
    sectionSeleccionarMascota.style.display = 'none'
    
    let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('chooseAttack')
    sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'block'
    
    let inputGarydous = document.getElementById('garydous')
    let inputChikbo = document.getElementById('chikbo')
    let inputSmyglet = document.getElementById('smyglet')
    let spanMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('allyPet')
    
    if (inputGarydous.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Garydous';
    } else if (inputChikbo.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Chikbo';
    } else if (inputSmyglet.checked) {
        spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Smyglet';
    } else {
        alert('Selecciona una mascota')
    }

    seleccionarMascotaEnemigo()
}

function seleccionarMascotaEnemigo() {
    let mascotaAleatoria = aleatorio(1,3)
    let spanMascotaEnemigo = document.getElementById('enemyPet')

    if (mascotaAleatoria == 1) {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Garydous'
    } else if (mascotaAleatoria == 2) {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Chikbo'
    } else {
        spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Smyglet'
    }
}

function ataqueFuego() {
    ataqueJugador = 'FUEGO'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueAgua() {
    ataqueJugador = 'AGUA'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueTierra() {
    ataqueJugador = 'TIERRA'
    ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}

function ataqueAleatorioEnemigo() {
    let ataqueAleatorio = aleatorio(1,3)
    
    if (ataqueAleatorio == 1) {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'FUEGO'
    } else if (ataqueAleatorio == 2) {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'AGUA'
    } else {
        ataqueEnemigo = 'TIERRA'
    }

    combate()
}

function combate() {
    let spanVidasJugador = document.getElementById('hpAllyPet')
    let spanVidasEnemigo = document.getElementById('hpEnemyPet')
    
    if(ataqueEnemigo == ataqueJugador) {
        crearMensaje("EMPATE")
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'FUEGO' && ataqueEnemigo == 'TIERRA') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'AGUA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'FUEGO') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else if(ataqueJugador == 'TIERRA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'AGUA') {
        crearMensaje("GANASTE")
        vidasEnemigo--
        spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
    } else {
        crearMensaje("PERDISTE")
        vidasJugador--
        spanVidasJugador.innerHTML = vidasJugador
    }

    revisarVidas()
}

function revisarVidas() {
    if (vidasEnemigo == 0) {
        crearMensajeFinal("FELICITACIONES! Ganaste :)")
    } else if (vidasJugador == 0) {
        crearMensajeFinal('Lo siento, perdiste :(')
    }
}

function crearMensaje(resultado) {
    let sectionalertsCombat = document.getElementById('alertsCombat')
    
    let parrafo = document.createElement('p')
    parrafo.innerHTML = 'Tu mascota atacó con ' + ataqueJugador + ', las mascota del enemigo atacó con ' + ataqueEnemigo + '- ' + resultado

    sectionalertsCombat.appendChild(parrafo)
}

function crearMensajeFinal(resultadoFinal) {
    let sectionalertsCombat = document.getElementById('alertsCombat')
    
    let parrafo = document.createElement('p')
    parrafo.innerHTML = resultadoFinal

    sectionalertsCombat.appendChild(parrafo)

    let botonFuego = document.getElementById('btnFire')
    botonFuego.disabled = true
    let botonAgua = document.getElementById('btnWater')
    botonAgua.disabled = true
    let botonTierra = document.getElementById('btnPlant')
    botonTierra.disabled = true

    let sectionreboot = document.getElementById('reboot')
    sectionreboot.style.display = 'block'
}

function rebootGame() {
    location.reload()
}

function aleatorio(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

window.addEventListener('load', iniciarJuego)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

body{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    background-color: #10A19D;
}


input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
input[type='radio']:checked + label {
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    border: #f0f8ff;
}
#title{
    color:#FF7000;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center; 
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    
}

#choosePet{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.subtitle{
    color: #FFBF00;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.petCard{
    width: 250px;
    height: 330px;
    background-color: #77037B;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid hotpink;
    color: #10A19D;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.petCard img{
    justify-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    

}

.btnStats{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 15px;
}
label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
.subtitle {
    font-size: 50px;
}

#btnPet{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    background-color: #B799FF;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow:
    inset -3px 3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    inset -3px -3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    inset 3px 1px 2px 2px #ACBCFF;
    position: relative;
}
#btnPet:focus{
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
#bntPet:visited{
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
}
#btnPet:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #B799FF;
    box-shadow:
    -3px 3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    -3px -3px 2px 2px #ACBCFF
    3px 1px 2px 2px #ACBCFF;
}
input:focus .label {
  color: #B799FF;
}
input:blur .label{
    color: #f0f8ff;
}
```

```html
label<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>MOKEPON!</title>
        <script src="./js/mokepon.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Mokepon! </h1>
        <section id="choosePet">
            

            <h2 class="subtitle">Elige tu mascota:</h2>

            <div class="btnStats">
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="garydous" />
                <label class="petCard" for="garydous">
                    <p>Garydous</p>
                    <img src="resources/Garydous.png" alt="Garydous">
                </label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="chikbo" />
                <label class="petCard" for="chikbo">
                    <p>Chikbo</p>
                    <img  src="resources/picathor.png" alt="Chikbo">
                </label>
                
                <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="smyglet" />
                <label class="petCard" for="smyglet">
                    <p>smyglet</p>
                    <img src="resources/smyglet.png" alt="Smyglet">
                </label>
            </div>
            

            <button id="btnPet">Vamos a Luchar</button>
        </section>

        <section id="chooseAttack">
            <h2>Elige tu ataque:</h2>

            <p>Tu mascota <span id="allyPet"></span> tiene <span id="hpAllyPet">3</span> vidas</p>
            <p>La mascota <span id="enemyPet"></span> del enemigo tiene <span id="hpEnemyPet">3</span> vidas</p>

            <p id="attacks">
                <button id="btnFire">Fuego </button>
                <button id="btnWater">Agua </button>
                <button id="btnPlant">Tierra </button>
            </p>
        </section>

        <section id="alertsCombat">
        </section>

        <section id="reboot">
            <button id="btnReboot">Reiniciar</button>
        </section>
    </body>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I tried to make it clearer and will keep that in mind.

Comment: Did this solve your problem or is there anything that this solution does not consider?